# 301 Redirects: Ignore Trailing Slashes and index.html

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

My client's existing site used URLs that could be in any one of these combinations:

```
site.com/canada/mountain_rail
site.com/canada/mountain_rail/
site.com/canada/mountain_rail/index.html
site.com/canada/mountain_rail/index.html/
```

Any URL might (or might not) have a trailing slash, and might (or might not) end with index.html. It's a bit of a nightmare.

I'm trying to write a 301 redirect that can take any one of those strings and redirect to a different page on their new site. What I have so far is this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^canada/mountain_rail$ /canada/mountain-rail-vacations? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

This works fine with URLs like `site.com/canada/mountain_rail`, but `site.com/canada/mountain_rail/` or `site.com/canada/mountain_rail/index.html` don't work and just return a 404.

Can anyone assist with this? I'm a bit of a beginner at Rewrite rules.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make trailing slash optional:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^canada/mountain_rail(?:/index\.html)?/?$ /canada/mountain-rail-vacations? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava. What happens if someone wants to access `canada/mountain_rail`, but the rewrite rule for `canada/` is above it in the .htaccess? Would it redirect to the first rule, as that is 'met' first? Hope that makes sense...

Comment: Rewrite rule should match for `^canada/?$` pattern then order doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer works perfectly for the first 3 URLs in my question, but the fourth one (`site.com/canada/mountain_rail/index.html/` - index.html AND a trailing slash) - fails. Is there a workaround?